# Error Logging into this app with facebook is not available at this time

Tags: react-native, facebook, expo, facebook-login, react-native-fbsdk

today i get into this error using react native with expo managed workflow, i try with facebook sdk, expo-auth-session, webview url, so them i give up because every method give me the same error, i end when i eject from expo to react native bare with react-native-fbsdk-next, after config all the environment with Android studio, i fall at the same error point D:

Please if someone know, if i missing some configurations, i follow all the steps in expo, react-native-fbsdk-next, expo-auth-session and expo-facebook D:

[Error Logging into this app with facebook is not available at this time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OxhS.jpg)

UPDATE: i created a new React Native project again from scratch, follow react-native-fbsdk-next and Facebook Android start guide for login, still getting the same error. I reach that the error occour when i need to type my account and password in the facebook app, if i was already loggued in and did not ask for new permissions, i can login sucessfully, but if i log out from facebook app or ask for 1 new permission, it force me to log in and the bug occurs again, also i reach this report at facebook page, if someone is getting the same error, please help comment:

[error logging facebook is not available at this time](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/3839475259507329/)